# Добавление / удаление css класса при свайпе влево / вправо на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

Есть код который выполняет добавление и удаление css класса при нажатии на элементы `slidenav-previous` и `slidenav-next`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(".slidenav-previous").click(function(){
      $(".continue_text").addClass("uk-hidden");
      $(".review_show_button").removeClass("uk-hidden");
    })
   $(".slidenav-next").click(function(){
      $(".continue_text").addClass("uk-hidden");
      $(".review_show_button").removeClass("uk-hidden");
   })   
});
```

Как дополнить эту функцию, чтобы добавление и удаление данных классов происходило еще и при свайпе влево / вправо.

Данный слайдер реализован на UIkit 2

Желаемого результата удалось добиться дополнив код следующим образом. Но как сделать чтобы функция выполнялась только при свайпах влево / вправо?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(".slidenav-previous").click(function(){
   $(".continue_text").addClass("uk-hidden");
   $(".review_show_button").removeClass("uk-hidden");
 })
 $(".slidenav-next").click(function(){
   $(".continue_text").addClass("uk-hidden");
   $(".review_show_button").removeClass("uk-hidden");
 }) 

 $( ".review_slide" ).on( "swipe", swipeHandler );

function swipeHandler( event ){
  $(".continue_text").addClass( "uk-hidden" );
  $(".review_show_button").removeClass("uk-hidden");
 }
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE спасибо, буду сейчас пробовать!

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE Мне удалось кое-что сделать благодаря Вашей ссылке, но не смог понять как сделать, чтобы функция выполнялась только при свайпах влево / вправо. Не могли бы Вы подсказать на этот счет. Спасибо

Comment: @anywaycode Мне удалось кое-что сделать благодаря Вашей ссылке, но не смог понять как сделать, чтобы функция выполнялась только при свайпах влево / вправо. Не могли бы Вы подсказать на этот счет. Спасибо

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE я дополнил свой вопрос кодом, который позволяет удалять/добавлять класс в моем случае при всех свайпах. Не могли бы взглянуть, что необходимо править, для срабатывания функции только лишь при свайпах влево / вправо

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".red").on("swipeleft", swipeHandler);
  $(".red").on("swiperight", swipeHandler);

  function swipeHandler(event) {
    $(event.target).removeClass("right left");
    event.type == 'swipeleft' ? $(event.target).addClass("left") : $(event.target).addClass("right");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.red.left {
  background-color: green;
}

.red.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="red">
</div>
```

Comment: c jquery.mobile-1.4.5 работать не хочет

Comment: @Ivan подключите 1.5.0-alpha.1, то что в script src

Comment: да я понял, но ведь это alpha. Stable version на jquerymobile.com сейчас 1.4.5. Возможно можно как то адаптировать под 1.4.5. И самое главное, что сам слайдер от uikit2 работает и на более низкой версии jquery. Все работает корректно, нужно только добавить к свайпу удаление / добавление класса. а как, увы знаний у меня нет :( . Не совсем понимаю зачем загружать альфу, когда на стабильной версии обычного jquery слайдер работает со своим набором функций без jquery mоbile